# delete rows from the employee table

Tags: oracle, plsql

Create a procedure that deletes rows from the employee table. it should accept 1 parameter, department name; only delete the employee records belonging to that department. display how many employees were deleted else raise "DeptNotFoundException" and print the message "No Records Found.".

```
Employee:

column name      datatype      constraints
EMP_ID           NUMBER(5)     PK
EMP_NMAE         VARCHAR2(25)  NOT NULL
SALARY           NUMBER(10,2) 
DEPT             VARCHAR2(25)

EMP_ID  EMP_NAME   SALARY    DEPT
101     JOHN       54000     MECH
102     TOM        43000     CSE
103     WILLIAM    34560     MECH
104     STEVE      56000     CSE
105     SMITH      23450     IT
```

and my code is,

```
set serveroutput on;

create or replace procedure delete_EMPLOYEE(dept_name in EMPLOYEE.dept%type) is

deptnotfound EXCEPTION;

begin

delete from EMPLOYEE where dept=dept_name;

if (sql%found) then

dbms_output.put_line(sql%rowcount || 'Employee record(s) got deleted.');

else

raise DeptNoFound;

end if;

EXCEPTION

when DeptNoFound then

dbms_output.put_line('No Records Found.');

end delete_EMPLOYEE;

/
```

it compiled successfully but not the test case. only 1 test case is passed instead of 2. can anyone help me out, please....

Comment: What "test case"? Procedure looks OK and works OK. It would help if you posted how you tested it.

Comment: @Would you like to share the failed test case scenarios ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
CREATE OR RPLACE PROCEDURE DELETE_EMPLOYEE(V_DEPT IN EMPLOYEE.DEPT%TYPE)
IS
DEPTNOTFOUNDEXCEPTION EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
DELETE FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE DEPT = V_DEPT;
IF SQL%FOUND THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' EMPLOYEE RECORS(S) GOT DELETED.');
ELSE
RAISE DEPTNOTFOUNDEXCEPTION;
END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN DEPTNOTFOUNDEXCEPTION THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO RECORDS FOUND.');
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared exception deptnotfound and while raising it you have spelled it incorrectly as deptnofound.